How to find the first market day of each month in Python?
I'm trying to figure out how to find the first market day of each month and to wait until each of those days after running some logic. I've figured out some of the code to be able to do this, but I can't get the code to be able to be something I can run month to month on a server or something.
Here is my code so far:
    nyse = mcal.get_calendar("XNYS")
    # Get the current time
    current_time = pd.Timestamp.now(tz="America/New_York").tz_localize(None)  # Ensure timezone-naive

    # Find the first market day of the coming month
    current_month = current_time.month
    current_year = current_time.year
    next_month = current_month + 1 if current_month < 12 else 1
    next_year = current_year + 1 if current_month == 12 else current_year

    # Initialize a variable to store the first market day
    first_market_day_next_month = None

    # Iterate through each day of the coming month until we find a market trading day
    for day in range(1, 32):
        try:
            date_candidate = pd.Timestamp(year=next_year, month=next_month, day=day)
            date_candidate = nyse.valid_days(start_date=date_candidate, end_date=date_candidate).tz_localize(None)  # Ensure timezone-naive
            if date_candidate is not None:
                first_market_day_next_month = date_candidate
                break
        except ValueError:
            # Handles cases where the day is out of range for the month
            pass
    first_market_day_next_month=first_market_day_next_month[0]
    market_open_time = nyse["market_open", f"{first_market_day_next_month}"]
    first_market_day_next_month=first_market_day_next_month.to_pydatetime()

    market_open_timestamp = pd.to_datetime(f'{first_market_day_next_month} {market_open_time}', format='mixed')

    # Calculate the time difference in seconds
    if market_open_timestamp is not None:
        time_difference_seconds = (market_open_timestamp - current_time).total_seconds()
        print("Time until market open on the first market day of the coming month (NYSE):", time_difference_seconds, "seconds")
    else:
        print("Unable to determine the first market day of the coming month.")
    return int(time_difference_seconds)

This code works for one iteration of this code, but it won't work for a month to month basis.
What would I have to adjust to be able to do this?

This can be done quite simply using the business day functionality in numpy.datetime.
Example:
Input: np.busday_offset('2024-05-01', 0, 'forward')
Output: numpy.datetime64('2024-05-01')
Input: np.busday_offset('2024-06-01', 0, 'forward') # This is a Saturday
Output: numpy.datetime64('2024-06-03')
Specific holidays can be added using numpy.busdaycalendar
Full code:
year = 2024

for month in range(1, 13):
    start_of_month = np.datetime64(f'{year}-{month:02}-01')
    first_bus_day = np.busday_offset(start_of_month, 0, 'forward')

    time_diff_seconds = np.timedelta64(first_bus_day - start_of_month, 's')

    print(start_of_month, first_bus_day, time_diff_seconds)


You have to take exchange holidays into account. The NYSE wasn't open on Jan 1, 2024 even though it was a Monday. That and its international aspect are the whole point of the pandas_market_calendars library.

THe library has a scheule function that returns the data you need:
nyse = mcal.get_calendar("NYSE")

# Find the first trading day of each month for next 12 months
start_date = pd.Timestamp.today().normalize() + pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1)
end_date = start_date + pd.offsets.MonthBegin(11)
first_trading_days = (
    nyse.schedule(start_date=start_date, end_date=end_date, tz=nyse.tz)
    .groupby(pd.Grouper("market_open", freq="MS"))["market_open"]
    .min()
)

